# Reliable information about x86 string instruction performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, x86

Common widsom is that `rep movsb` is much slower than `rep movsd` (or on 64-bit, `rep movsq`) when performing identical operations. However, I've been testing on a few modern machines, and the run times are coming out identical (up to measurement noise) across a huge range of buffer sizes (10 bytes to 2 megs). So far I have just tested on 2 machines (32-bit Intel Atom D510 and 64-bit AMD FX 8120).

- Are there any modern x86 (32- or 64-bit) machines where `rep movsb` is slower than `rep movsd` (or `rep movsq`)?
- If not, what was the last machine where the difference was significant, and how significant was it?

I'm asking this question from a standpoint of wanting to avoid cargo-culting a bunch of tests to break memory up into unaligned head/tail and aligned middle for the sake of using `rep movsd` or `rep movsq` if there's no actual benefit to doing this...

Comment: Your performance results for modern machines is correct.

Comment: It is throttled by the memory bus bandwidth, not the cpu.

Comment: In theory that's probably true, but other ways of copying (e.g. C loops) are 2-8x slower. So the cpu time spent is making a difference.

Comment: related: [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231).  And BTW, I think http://agner.org/optimize/ reported that a misaligned starting address makes the whole `rep stos` or `rep movs` operation slower on Intel CPUs at least.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lots of benchmarks here: [instlatx64.atw.hu](http://instlatx64.atw.hu/)

For example (Intel Core 2 Duo E6700):

```
REP MOVSB   BW in L1D:13.04 B/c  34829MiB/s
REP MOVSW   BW in L1D:13.29 B/c  35493MiB/s
REP MOVSD   BW in L1D:13.40 B/c  35783MiB/s
```

Which shows that there *is* a difference, but it's tiny.

This one for SandyBridge is a little weird:

```
REP MOVSB   BW in L1D:25.50 B/c  86986MiB/s
REP MOVSW   BW in L1D:18.09 B/c  61721MiB/s
REP MOVSD   BW in L1D:27.47 B/c  93693MiB/s
```

Seems there is a big difference on some Atoms (seems to have disappeared with the D5xx, so you just missed it):

```
REP MOVSB   BW in L1D: 0.53 B/c    990MiB/s
REP MOVSW   BW in L1D: 1.93 B/c   3598MiB/s
REP MOVSD   BW in L1D: 3.74 B/c   6960MiB/s
```

I haven't found such big difference on anything else that can be considered new.